# Why is isNaN("1") false?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple test for the input of a function to determine if all of the inputs are numbers or not.

```
function numbers(){
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
   if (isNaN(arguments[i])) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

However, when I pass in a list of numbers as characters (eg. numbers("1", "2")) I get `true` instead of the expected `false`.

Comment: Are you passing it strings as opposed to numbers?

Comment: isNaN does not check the type, in simple terms it just sees if it's a number (more specifically, if it's not a number), even if it's a number inside a string.

Comment: `isNaN` isn't meant to be used to determine whether or not the argument is a number. It's meant to be used to determine whether or not the argument is a floating-point NaN value.

Comment: @user2357112—where did you get that idea? [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4) says "Returns true if the argument coerces to NaN", e.g. `isNaN(new Date('foo'))` returns true, `isNaN(Infinity)` returns false.

Comment: @Spinlock—javascript is loosely typed, type checking is frequently counter productive. Better to ensure the correct type only where actually required (e.g. where `+` should perform addition, not concatenation).

Comment: Use [`Number.isNaN`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isNaN` implicitly coerces the argument to Number, and then checks whether this coerced value is NaN.
See http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.4

That is, `isNaN(foo)` is equivalent to `isNaN(Number(foo))`

Code fix:

```
if (typeof arguments[i] !== 'number' || isNaN(arguments[i])) return false;
```

The second part of the condition is because `typeof NaN === 'number'`.

---

Your function might be a bit more readable in functional style, using ES5's [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method:

```
//returns whether all arguments are of type Number and not NaN
function numbers() {
    return [].every.call(arguments, function(arg) {
        return typeof arg === 'number' && !isNaN(arg);
    });
}
```

Comment: And because `NaN !== NaN` per the [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6). However it isn't required in order to test for `NaN` as `x !== x` **only** returns `true` if `x` is `NaN` (though it is handy and more expressive).

Comment: @RobG Yes, thanks for mentioning that `NaN !== NaN`, guess I subconsciously skipped it as anyone who already tried comparing a NaN result with === NaN would know that bit `=]`. The `x !== x` trick is documented in the annotated ES link which I posted as well (though I prefer the `isNaN` function for expressiveness). Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

`isNan()` will attempt to cast it to a number, and then check. I would use this instead

```
if(!isNaN(parseFloat(arguments[i])) && isFinite(arguments[i])){
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery, you could use its built-in `$.isNumeric()` function