# isNaN(1) and isNaN("1") returns false

Tags: javascript

Why in my screenshot below `isNaN(1)` and `isNaN("1")` returns `false`? As one of them is number and one of them is a string so isNaN("1") should return true.

[image]

Comment: Did you do any research on this? A simple reference to MDN can usually help

Comment: or stackoverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177042 http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isnan+javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

> When the argument to the `isNaN` function is not of type Number, **the value is first coerced to a Number**. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected; the empty string, for example, is surely "not a number."

The article also suggests using the (*experiemental*) [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) function if you don't want this behavior:

```
console.log(Number.isNaN("1")) // false
console.log(Number.isNaN(NaN)) // true
```

Or more simply:

```
console.log("1" != "1") // false
console.log(NaN != NaN) // true
```

But if what you really want to simply determine if a value of type `Number` (and not for example, of type `String`), simply use `typeof`:

```
console.log(typeof "1" == "number") // false
console.log(typeof 1 == "number")   // true
```

But this will return `true` for `NaN` because despite being known as 'not a number', it's actually a value of type `Number`. If you want to ensure that the value is of type `Number`, and a valid, finite number use the (*experimental*) [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite):

```
console.log(Number.isFinite("1")) // false
console.log(Number.isFinite(1))   // true
console.log(Number.isFinite(NaN)) // false
```

Or simply create your own:

```
function myIsFinite(x) { return typeof x == "number" && isFinite(x); }
console.log(myIsFinite("1")) // false
console.log(myIsFinite(1))   // true
console.log(myIsFinite(NaN)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The `isNaN` function will convert the input to a number first and then determine if the resulting number is NaN.